# How to check if a label having attribute for="admin_emal" exists using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a label generated like this. This one is generated from jquery validation.

```
 <label for="admin_email" generated="true" class="error" style="display: inline-block;">Please provide admin username</label>
```

I need to check if the label with `for="admin_email"` exists.

I know that for id, I can use something like this:-

```
if($('#some_id').length > 0)
{
    .......
}
```

How can I do the same with `for="admin_email"`?

Comment: maybe this works `$('label[for="admin_email"]').length`

Comment: `$('label[for="admin_email"]').length`

Comment: `$("[for='admin_email']")` should work. See jquery [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($('label[for="admin_email"]').length > 0) {
  // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selectors, so for example `label[for="admin_email"]`

```js
if($('label[for="admin_email"]').length === 1) {
    console.log('for="admin_email" exists');
} else {
    console.log('for="admin_email" does not exist');
}

if($('label[for="admin_email_label_that_doesnt_exist"]').length === 1) {
    console.log('for="admin_email_label_that_doesnt_exist" exists');
} else {
    console.log('for="admin_email_label_that_doesnt_exist" does not exist');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="admin_email" generated="true" class="error" style="display: inline-block;">Please provide admin username</label>
```